# MongoDB - Mongoose.model.find returning an empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple Node.js app and I'm trying to communicate to MongoDB on localhost, but I can't seem to get any of the documents stored in the DB to be returned when I do a mongoose.model.find

There are clearly 2 documents in my DB when I use compass to explore it:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
var DB_HOST = 'localhost'
var DB_PORT = 27017

const options = {
    poolSize: 1000,
    keepAlive: 6000000,
    connectTimeoutMS: 6000000,
    autoReconnect: true,
    reconnectTries: 300000,
    reconnectInterval: 5000,
    useNewUrlParser: true
  };

module.exports = {
    'options' : options,
    'url' : 'mongodb://'+DB_HOST+':'+DB_PORT
};

mongoose.connect(configDB.url, configDB.options);

...

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const messagesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    message: { type: String, required: true },
    year: { type: String, required: true }
});

const Message = mongoose.model('Message', messagesSchema);

async function getMessagesByYear(req, res) {
    try {
        const queryYear = req.headers.query;
        console.log("Get Messages by Year " + queryYear);

        const messages = await Message.find({ year: queryYear });
        console.log('messages: ' + messages);
        res.status(200).json(messages);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Unable to get messages", err);
        res.status(400).json({ message: "Unable to get messages" });
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or help will be appreciated!

Tried stepping through the code in debug mode, added printouts but can't see why the above function returns an empty array. Also checked the connection to my DB and it displays the correct status (2)

Comment: Also note: I have 'Query: 2020' in the header of my request (req.headers.query)

Comment: Where does that collection come from? It's not named in a way that would allow mongoose to find it by default. Also it's best to embed images in your question rather than just links.

Comment: Try specifying collection name manually in the schema. May by default it may be using different collection name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model will reference a collection named `messages` but the collection in your database is named `Messages`. You can either rename the collection, or specify the collection when making the model, like so:

```js
const Message = mongoose.model('Message', messagesSchema, 'Messages');
```

Conventionally, collections are lowercase, so I recommend renaming the collection.

It also doesn't look like you're specifying the database to use when making a connection. You can either do this in the connection URI itself, or in the connection options. Doing it in the connection URI (which is the more common way) would look like this:

```js
'mongodb://'+DB_HOST+':'+DB_PORT+'/message'
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the modified code and renamed the collection but still no luck

Comment: Can you show where you call mongoose.connect(), including the URI you pass to it (but with username and password and domain name censored).

Comment: Updated it to show that info you requested

Comment: Looks like there's an issue there too, updated to address that as well.

Comment: Thank you sir! Won't be making that mistake again

Comment: Glad if I could help :)